# Trying to remove leading zero and white spaces using REGEX

Tags: regex

I have a series of phone numbers that I need to remove the leading zeros and any spaces between the numbers from.

So far I have got the following Regex expression:

```
^[^1-9A-Z]+
```

But need to add the ability to remove any spaces between numbers.

For example I want

```
012345 6789
```

to become:

```
123456789
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What programming language (or interface) are you working with?

Comment: google sheets: regexreplace(to_text(D2),"^[^1-9A-Z]+","")

Comment: What do you want as output for `0000 01234`? `1234` or `01234`?

Comment: output of "0000 01234" to be 1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replace this pattern with an empty string:

```
^0+|\s+
```

The regex consists of two parts, `^0+` and `\s+`. The regex will match when any of these parts matches. `^0+` matches one or more 0s at the start of the string. `\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `|` to select either the leading zeros/non-number/non-word characters, OR any spaces, and replace with the empty string:

```
/^[^1-9A-Z]+|\s/
```

https://regex101.com/r/j9VJSA/1

Comment: Thank you but there were some spaces not being detected in-between the numbers not sure if they had come in with different encoding

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "012345 6789" | sed -e 's/^0*//' -e 's/\([0-9]*\)\s\([0-9]*\)/\1\2/g'    
123456789

$ echo "012345 6789 876" | sed -e 's/^0*//' -e 's/\([0-9]*\)\s\([0-9]*\)/\1\2/g'    
123456789876

$ echo "0012345 6789 876 54" | sed -e 's/^0*//' -e 's/\([0-9]*\)\s\([0-9]*\)/\1\2/g'    
12345678987654
```

Explain:

- `^0*` to match all leading 0
- `\s` means space
- `[0-9]` to match any single number
- `[0-9]*` to match any numbers
- `\(` and `\)`  use to group
- `\1` and `\2` to pick the group